# Parse XML with multilevel nesting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to Parse some XML having multiple nesting levels in SQL. The problem I hit into here is how to write my query generic enough for it to Parse the XML below without having to hard-code the node path e:g

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @xml

INSERT #Root(ID)
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/Root')
WITH (ID VARCHAR(100))

INSERT #ConditionSet(Operator)
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/Root/ConditionSet')
WITH (Operator VARCHAR(100))

INSERT #ConditionSet(Operator)
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/Root/ConditionSet/ConditionSet')
WITH (Operator VARCHAR(100))

INSERT #ConditionSet(Operator)
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@handle, '/Root/ConditionSet/ConditionSet/ConditionSet')
WITH (Operator VARCHAR(100))
```

Is there a better way to Parse the following XML **in SQL** and represent all data in tabular form?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<Root ID="414141" Source="AudienceBuilder">
  -<ConditionSet Operator="I">
    -<Condition Operator="E" ID="74373">
      -<Relationship ID="56756">
        <Relationship ID="67868"/>
      </Relationship>
      -<Value>
        <![CDATA[ABC]]>
      </Value>
    </Condition>
    -<ConditionSet Operator="O">
      -<Condition Operator="E" ID="6566">
        -<Relationship ID="7658">
          <Relationship ID="6547"/>
        </Relationship>
        -<Value>
          <![CDATA[DEF]]>
        </Value>
      </Condition>
      -<Condition Operator="E" ID="96967">
        -<Relationship ID="3884">
          <Relationship ID="9954"/>
        </Relationship>
        -<Value>
          <![CDATA[GHI]]>
        </Value>
      </Condition>
      -<ConditionSet Operator="A">
        -<Condition Operator="E" ID="31654">
          -<Relationship ID="57894">
            <Relationship ID="8532"/>
          </Relationship>
          -<Value>
            <![CDATA[JKL]]>
          </Value>
        </Condition>
        -<Condition Operator="E" ID="65636">
          -<Relationship ID="843">
            <Relationship ID="7473"/>
          </Relationship>
          -<Value>
            <![CDATA[MNO]]>
          </Value>
        </Condition>
      </ConditionSet>
    </ConditionSet>
  </ConditionSet>
</Root>
```

Any inputs/recommendations are highly appreciated :)

Thank you

Zeaous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your XML in a SQL Server variable called `@XML`, you can use the **native XQuery** support in SQL Server 2005 and newer to do this much more elegantly and efficiently:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '...(your XML here).....' 

SELECT
    RootID = @xml.value('(/Root/@ID)[1]', 'int'),
    ConditionSetOperator = XC.value('@Operator', 'varchar(50)'),
    ConditionID =  XC2.value('@ID', 'int'),
    ConditionOperator = XC2.value('@Operator', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @Xml.nodes('//ConditionSet') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    xc.nodes('Condition') AS XT2(XC2)
```

This gives me an output of

[image]

With XQuery operators like `.nodes()` or `.value()`, you can easily "shred" an XML document into relational data and store that as needed.

The first call to `@xml.nodes('//ConditionSet')` will get a "pseudo" table for each matching node - so each `<ConditionSet>` node will be returned in the "pseudo" table `XT` as column `XC`, and then I can easily grab attributes (or XML elements) from that XML fragment using XQuery methods like `.value()`.

Or I can even grab the list of sub-nodes `<Condition>` for each of those `<ConditionSet>` nodes - using the `CROSS APPLY` with a second call to `.nodes()`